# Query Problem on _prepareCollection()

Tags: magento-1.9, mysql, php-5.4, sales-order, query

how to convert mysql query to magento query

**mysql query**

```
SELECT  `p`.`product_id` ,  `p`.`name` ,  `o`.`increment_id` 
FROM  `sales_flat_order_item` AS  `p` 
LEFT JOIN  `sales_flat_order` AS  `o` ON  `p`.`order_id` =  `o`.`entity_id` where `o`.`increment_id` = 10000001
```

**magento query**

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection');      
        $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft( array('p'
        =>  Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('sales_flat_order_item')),
            array('main_table.entity_id = p.order_id')->where('main_table.increment_id=',$order_id)););
        $this->setCollection($collection);
        parent::_prepareCollection();
        return $this;
    }
```

I tried below query but it's not getting any result.

how to map above mysql query to `$collection`;

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection');
$collection->addFieldToSelect('increment_id')
    ->getSelect()->joinLeft(array('item' => $collection->getTable('sales/order_item')),
        'item.order_id = main_table.entity_id',
        array('item.product_id', 'item.name'))
    ->where('main_table.increment_id = ?', '100000090');
```

Comment: i will come back after I tried..